# SignalR Self Host on Ubuntu Server error

Tags: c#, linux, ubuntu, mono, signalr

i have a virtual machine on Azure.My server is Ubuntu Server 12.04.My aim is using SignalR self host on it. For that  i install Mono Develop on ubuntu server and write the example my code. [(Microsoft Tutorial)](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/tutorial-signalr-20-self-host) For firewall i disabled firewall on Ubuntu and added an endpoint 1453* in Azure Virtual Machine.

i added all references to my project and build it.Everything is okay project is running and listening the port 1453. But when i call signalr from my localhost (not in the ubuntu) i get some erros.i take a snapshot of the error:

[image: Error]

Whats wrong with my code? or did i forget some references? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

[UPDATE]
i copied that packages from Nuget to Mono
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.SelfHost
Install-Package Microsoft.Owin.Cors

Comment: What version of each dependency are you using? Looks like you have SignalR 1.0 and 2.0 binaries mixed in your application.

Comment: @dfowler i'm trying to use signalR 2.0

Comment: What are the versions of all of the packages you are using? Can you update the question with that?

Comment: @dfowler i updated it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finnaly, i found! The problem is i missed to add some dll's to my project on Mono. The clear way to do that, copy the project that runs in your local Windows to Ubuntu Server.Open a new project in Mono , copy the code and add all the references. Remember that use framework 4.5 and add references of 4.5 version.

References you should have to add:

- System.Web.Cors
- Microsoft.AspNet.Signalr.Core
- Microsoft.Owin
- Microsoft.Owin.Cors
- Microsoft.Owin.Diagnostics
- Microsoft.Owin.Host.HttpListener
- Microsoft.Owin.Hosting
- Microsoft.Owin.Security
- Newtonsfot.Json
- Owin.dll
- Microsoft.Csharp
- System.Core
- System.Data
- System.Data.SetExtensions
- System.Xml
- System.Xml.Linq